# How to stack columns in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I received an assignment to stack columns in MS Excel using VBA.
[image: data]

The result should look like:
[image: result]

I found the following VBA script online (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4233-excel-stack-columns.html):

```vb
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set Range1 = Application.Selection
    Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, 
    Range1.Address, Type:=8)
    Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    rowIndex = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
        Rng.Copy
        Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
        rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Result:
[image: not the result OP expected]

I did not expect that the dashes would be at the "bottom of the stack".

Comment: Did you debug your macro?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the columns and don't transpose the paste.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng As Range
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", "Select range", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", "Select range", Type:=8)
    rowIndex = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each rng In rng1.Columns
        rng.Copy
        rng2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        rowIndex = rowIndex + rng.Rows.Count
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your tags do not include any version limitations, you can do this with a formula:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("~",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(Table2[#All])),,"~")
```

or, if you don't want to use **Tables**:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("~",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(cell_Range_reference),,"~")
```